# Magento 2 add a field to front account information tab

Tags: magento2, module, attributes, customer, frontend

I'm trying to add a custom text field to the edit account information page on frontend customer dashboard, so i tried to create a module 
[image]
like this in

> VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\InstallData.php

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Wetag\InvoiceEmail\Setup\CustomerSetup');
            $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



    }

}
```

And in

> VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\CustomerSetup.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

protected $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    Context $context,
    CacheInterface $cache,
    CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
    Config $eavConfig
    ) {
    $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
} 

public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
    $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
    $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
} 

public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


    $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'invoice_email',
        [
        'label' => 'invoice email',
        'system' => 0,
        'position' => 100,
        'sort_order' =>100,
        'visible' =>  true,
        'note' => '',


                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'input' => 'text',

        ]
        );

    $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'invoice_email')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['customer_account_edit']) -> save();


} 

public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

} 

public function getEavConfig() {
    return $this -> eavConfig;
} 
}
```

The attribute is added on backend but not on frontend, I saw a post saying to override Magento template, so how to do it, if some one give me the steps to follow to display the field on customer account edit page on front.

Comment: Yes, you need to override the template (phtml).

Comment: @AmitBera please how  and which file i'm magento newbie

Comment: can you find any solution for your problem

Comment: I overrided the layouts and templates see here file structure https://ibb.co/rtPxDYX

Comment: @tarekfellah can you please share the answer here?